# Changing the status of columns(collapse/expanded) in a GridPanel is not saved in memory when u refresh

Tags: extjs

My problem is that when I collapse/expand columns and I refresh the page the propperty is not saved, but when I collapse/expand columns and  also I move the position of one column this one is saved with the other propperty and when I refresh the page I vusualized the columns with the modifys. Do you know what I am missing? Why this expand/collapse property is not saved in the first case?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, [stateEvents](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-stateEvents) property is explicitly redefined somewhere.

Sorry, I don’t know which version you are using, but read about the `Ext.state.Stateful` component

Comment: I'm using the 4.2 version.

Comment: Then try to watch https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.state.Stateful. This is all I can help without code samples.